# From a list of 'Likes', how can you see all profiles that are public?

Tags: instagram

The only method that I know is too inefficient: click on each profile and then see whether that profile is public or private.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the native app or the web app?

Comment: @Alex I do not understand what you mean, sorry. I use Bluestacks to access Instagram.

Comment: Instagram is the app on your mobile phone? Or are you accessing it from your browser?

Comment: @Alex I access it on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this using the UI. You'll have to make use of the Instagram API to get the list of users that like a image and then lookup each account to see if it's private.

Another way is to create a tool that crawls the Instagram site, i.e. you give it the url to a post, it navigates to each user that liked it, and it checks if they are private.

There may be existing apps or Chrome extensions that do this.